# jquery focus, when unfocus change back to original css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this script in jQuery:

```
<script>
$('#searchbar').focus(function(){
    $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'red');
});
</script>
```

When you focus the child in the parent the parents background turns red. But when you leave focus it is still red. How do i make it change to another color, lets say blue, when you unfocus the child?

The child is a form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a focusout function

```
$('#searchbar').focus(function(){
    $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'red');
}).blur(function() {
    //do what you need
    $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'blue');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was a quick answer. Have a nice day!

Comment: ITYM `blur` - the `focusout` event corresponds to the `focusin` event.

Comment: Definitely use `blur`. `The focusout event is sent to an element when it, or any element inside of it, loses focus. This is distinct from the blur event in that it supports detecting the loss of focus on descendant elements (in other words, it supports event bubbling).`

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[blur()](http://api.jquery.com/blur/)**:

```
$('#searchbar').blur(function() {
    $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'black');
});
```